# Custom RouteReuseStrategy for components of child module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-forms

Angular **v-15.2.7**

I don't want loose form data after re-routing. So I am trying implement **RouteReuseStrategy**.
My app structure is little different. My components are inside a module(ex customer-routing.module.ts)  but routes are defined in root level(i,e in **app.routing.module.ts**).

**customer-routing.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    
    const routes: Routes = [];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class CustomerRoutingModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NoaccessComponent } from './core/components/noaccess/noaccess.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './core/authguard/auth.guard';
import { CustomerCreationComponent } from './modules/customer/components/customer-creation/customer-creation.component';
import { CustomerViewComponent } from './modules/customer/components/customer-view/customer-view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'master',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: AppComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'create/:email/:phnNumber',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component:CustomerCreationComponent,
       data: {
       shouldReuseRoute: true,
       reuseRoutesFrom: ['master', 'view/:email/:phnNumber']
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'view/:email/:phnNumber',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component:CustomerViewComponent
  },
  {
    path:'accessdenied',
    component: NoaccessComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './modules/shared/material.module';
import { HeaderComponent } from './core/components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './core/components/footer/footer.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NoaccessComponent } from './core/components/noaccess/noaccess.component';
import { CustomerModule } from './modules/customer/customer.module';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerRouteReuseStrategy } from './router-strategy';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    NoaccessComponent,  
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CustomerModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: CustomerRouteReuseStrategy
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**router-stretegy.ts**

```
import {RouteReuseStrategy,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,DetachedRouteHandle,} from '@angular/router';
  
  export class CustomerRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
    private routeLeftFrom: string | undefined;
    private handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};
  
    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
      this.routeLeftFrom = route.routeConfig!.path;
        return route.data['shouldReuseRoute'] || false;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handler: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
      console.log('[router-reuse] storing handler');
      if (handler) {
        this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)] = handler;
      }
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
      var wasRoutePreviouslyDetached = !!this.handlers[route.url.join('/') || route.parent!.url.join('/')];
        if (wasRoutePreviouslyDetached) {
            var reuseRouteFromVerified = route.data['reuseRoutesFrom'].indexOf(this.routeLeftFrom) > -1;

            if (reuseRouteFromVerified) {

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
        if (!route.routeConfig || route.routeConfig.loadChildren) {
          return null;
        }
      
        return this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)];
      }      
  
    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
      let reUseUrl = false;
  
      if (future.routeConfig) {
        if (future.routeConfig.data) {
          reUseUrl = future.routeConfig.data['reuse'];
        }
      }
      const defaultReuse = future.routeConfig === current.routeConfig;
  
      return reUseUrl || defaultReuse;
    }
  
    getUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
        if (route.routeConfig) {
          const url = route.routeConfig.path;
          console.log('[router-reuse] returning url', url);
      
          return url as string; 
        }
      
        throw new Error('Route configuration is missing for the provided route.');
    }
  }
```

Issues is: **Re-routing without params is working fine. But with params the form data is vanishing**.

Comment: does the created stackblitz contain the issue?

Comment: complex forms might have this issue, since lots of data needs to stored in memory, just store the form in a service and patch value when all the dropdowns have loaded

Comment: No, **stackblitz** is fine. Facing issues in my app. I just tried with simple input field. Still its not storing the data. **Stackblitz** is just added to show the working solution.

Comment: is it ok, if we store the value in a service and patch value the details when navigation happens?

Comment: No, Many of the form field data is based on 1 other & 1-3 api call involves.

Comment: you can make the calls again and patch value, that will be the simplest solution, we just need to write the function that does this on navigationend event

Comment: No, My form flow is different. 1 input field filled then api call. Then, dropdown values will be updated. Then dropdown select, Then 1more api gets called. Its harder to change the whole component.

Comment: another option is when back button gets pressed you refresh the screen? that will eliminate maintaining in state. SPA all have this problem with the back button!

Comment: Can you provide **stackblitz** ref in angular-15. Like mine.

Comment: ok give me some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256557/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-shankar).

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using the root level injected service. On component ngDestroy event you can save the object in the service variable and when revisiting the page you can read it from service.

1. Create the root level service

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

   @Injectable()
   export class AppService {
      private formData;

     setFormData(formData) {
       this.formData = formData;
     }

     getFormData() {
       return this.formData;
    }
   }
   ```
2. Set from data to service variable on component destroy event

   ```
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.appService.setFormData(this.contactForm.getRawValue());
    }
   ```
3. Set form form from service on ngOnInit event

   ```
    setFormData() {
       const data = this.appService.getFormData();
       if (data) {
          this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
            title: new FormControl(),
            name: new FormControl(data.name),
            university: new FormControl(),
            course: new FormControl(),
         });
       } else {
         // initialise contact form
       }
    }
   ```

Check this out -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-reactive-forms-validation-rqhd6v

Comment: This approach won’t suite to my requirement. My form data is dependent upon many api calls.

Comment: Okay, my understanding is - you required the form data when you revisit the page and its their. and its upto you how you manage the API calls.